# Angular pretty URL's not working and leaving console errors

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to build my first angular app only the html5mode url's isn't working?

```
    var app = angular.module('vennDigital', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {


        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "partials/home.html", 
            controller: "HomeCtrl"
            }
        )
        .when("/about", {
            templateUrl: "partials/about.html", 
            controller: "AboutCtrl"
            }
        )
        .when("/services", {
             templateUrl: "partials/services.html", 
             controller: "ServiceCtrl"
             }
        );

     // use the HTML5 History API
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


    }]);


    app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-home';
    });

    app.controller('AboutCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-about';
    });

    app.controller('ServiceCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-contact';
    });
```

Comment: did you added `<base href="/" >` in `head` section? otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 0):

If you have put `<base href="/" >` in your index html file, try to comment it out. Or you can change the value of href to what ever you want.